# Play 2.1.4 java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

My project run well before, but yesterday after I cleaned the project, and run it again, found the following error message:

```
[error] application - 

! @6g0a10lp6 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/mvc/Result;]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/mvc/Result;
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.mvc.Action.call(Lplay/mvc/Http$Context;)Lplay/mvc/Result;
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:80) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:79) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:425) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.4]
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

this is weird, I didn't modify anything, is it because I'm using new securesocial?
at first I got warning like:

```
[warn] potential incompatible ....
[warn] org.scala-lang: 2.10.2, 2.10.0
```

then I added the following line to Build.scala:

```
"securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT" exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect"),
```

the warning is gone.

Comment: you have to upgrade to Play 2.2, new securesocial plugin isn't compatible with Play 2.1 due to the difference in Scala versions. And if you excluded Scala stuff at all, then it can't use the Scala classes it probably needs.